# NSDate is coming nil while converting a date string having 12 hour format to NSDate if iPhone/iPad is in 24 hour format

Tags: objective-c, ios7, nsdate, nsdateformatter

In my Application,Client's requirement is to display Time in 12 hour format.Everything is working fine if my device is not in  24 time format .But If I change the device time format to 24 hour format,mydate is coming nil.Here is My code.

```
NSString *timeStr=@"12-02-2012 11:12 PM";
NSDateFormatter *dtf = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dtf setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm a"];
NSDate *myDate=[dtf dateFromString:timeStr];
```

Please give a solution.I am validating the date of datePicker by taking mydate and my app is crashing because of nil value.Thanks in advance.

Comment: how can a 24 hour format has am/pm. remove `a` in `[dtf setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm a"];`

Comment: In my app I am getting the time from server and converting it to 12 hour format and displaying it in a label.I just want to convert the date string(text of label) having 12 hour format to NSDate.But I am getting nil,IF DEVICE IS IN 24 HOUR FORMAT.If device is in 12 hour format,I am able to convert it to NSDate..

Comment: MKR ,My date string i.e timeStr is in 12 hour format,not in 24 hour. if I remove a in [dtf setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm a"], how formatter can know that date string is in 12 hour format?

Comment: before setting dateFormat set locale:    dtf.locale = NSLocale.systemLocale;

Answer (score 2):

I got my solution by setting Locale for the formatter and I am getting NSDate,if device is in 24 hour format.Here is the Code.

```
 NSString *timeStr=@"12-02-2012 11:12 PM";
    NSDateFormatter *dtf = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dtf setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm a"];
    [dtf setFormatterBehavior:NSDateFormatterBehaviorDefault];
    NSDate *datens= [[NSDate alloc]init];
    NSLocale *curentLocale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
    [dtf setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:[curentLocale localeIdentifier]]];
```